# difference b/n on foot and walking in activity recognition

Tags: android, activity-recognition

In Android 4.4 google play services introduced "walking" activity Recognition but there is already on_foot recognition.

- What is the difference between the both?

Answer (score 5):

As per https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity

ON_FOOT: "The device is on a user who is walking or running."

WALKING: "The device is on a user who is walking. This is a sub-activity of ON_FOOT."

RUNNING: "The device is on a user who is running. This is a sub-activity of ON_FOOT."